# Dynamic select-option in SAP ABAP

Tags: dynamic, popup, abap, sap-selection-screens

I am looking to make a selection screen in which I have to take an input of the table name and then based of which table is selected I have to ask for some parameters.

I tried to use `POPUP_TO_GET_VALUE / POPUP_GET_VALUES` but it does not help because I need to use select option instead of just value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dynamic select options you can use free selections. Wrote a little sample program to demonstrate the usage. You can check the FM's documentation and FM's parameters for more customized behavior.

```
TYPE-POOLS: rsds.

DATA: ls_field  TYPE rsdsfields,
      lt_field  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF rsdsfields,
      l_selid   TYPE dynselid,
      l_repid   TYPE sy-repid,
      ls_pfkey  TYPE rsdspfkey,
      lt_trange TYPE rsds_trange.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  ls_field-tablename = 'T001'.
  ls_field-fieldname = 'BUKRS'.
  ls_field-type = 'S'.
  APPEND ls_field TO lt_field.

  CALL FUNCTION 'FREE_SELECTIONS_INIT'
    EXPORTING
      kind         = 'F'
    IMPORTING
      selection_id = l_selid
    TABLES
      fields_tab   = lt_field[].

  ls_pfkey-program = sy-repid.

  CALL FUNCTION 'FREE_SELECTIONS_DIALOG'
    EXPORTING
      selection_id    = l_selid
      title           = 'Select Company'
      as_window       = 'X'
      pfkey           = ls_pfkey
      tree_visible    = ''
    IMPORTING
      field_ranges    = lt_trange
    TABLES
      fields_tab      = lt_field[]
    EXCEPTIONS
      internal_error  = 1
      no_action       = 2
      selid_not_found = 3
      illegal_status  = 4
      OTHERS          = 5.
```

The user selection can be found in `lt_trange`.